# split text with delimiters + int between 0-9

Tags: java, android, string, colors, split

I have to write a function that display string typed by the user ,  with color in a textview.

Exemple : `^1Hi ^2 everyone`:

- "Hi" = red color because because there is "^1" before
- "Everyone" = green color beacause there is  "^2" before.

So I think I have to use split function like this :

```
String txt = myEditText.getText().toString();
String[] splits = txt.split("\\^(\\d+)");
```

But I don't know how to get number typed after "^".

And then I want to assign a color with the number typed.

And I think I can use :

```
MyTextView.setText(HTML.fromHtml(myTextModifiedWithColor);
```

So if you have any idea, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you only split on `^` for a simple reason: your array will be filled with strings terminated by `^` and starting with a number.

Now you can easily process all strings by simply removing the last character if it is a `^` because you don't want to display that. In addition, you want to read the first character of each string, and adjust the colour accordingly. don't forget to remove that character as well.

To trim your strings, I would suggest using `substring()`. To apply colour, I'd suggest using a `switch` statement.

Also, don't forget that your first string will likely either be useless or not start with a number. In any case, just be sure to check the consistency of all strings. I would also highly recommend you use another way of applying mark-up. If you really want to be fancy, you could use the `replace()` method with a more complex `RegEx` to replace your markup with proper `HTML` mark-up and then just visualise it as is by using `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourString));`.

Comment: Can you give me a code that use what you said ?

Comment: i think dits a good idea but i dont know show to make this :s

Comment: `HTML` has a `colour` attribute for the `font`tag. You can find `HTML` tutorials at w3schools; http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp